# Bash command - using IF - FI within a DO - DONE

Tags: bash, command

I'm trying to run a command that should find PHP files that contain "base64_decode" and/or "eval", echo the file name, print the top three lines, if the file contains more than 3 lines, also the bottom 3.

I have the following at the moment:

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.php" -exec grep -il "base64_decode\|eval" {} \;); do echo $file; head -n 3 $file; if [ wc -l < $file -gt 3 ]; then tail -n 3 $file fi; done | less
```

This returns the following error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

Comment: Why making such long one-liners? Give some format to it. The issue is probably with `if [ wc -l < $file -gt 3 ]; then `, it looks wrong. Use shellcheck to get some output and ask something specific here, we are not supposed to check your code :)

Comment: In addition to the missing `$()`, you need a semicolon before `fi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would to use the following

```
while read -r file
do
        echo  ==$file==
        head -n 3 "$file"
        [[ $(grep -c '' "$file") > 3 ]] && (echo ----last-3-lines--- ; tail -n 3 "$file")
done < <(find . -name \*.php -exec grep -il 'base64_decode\|eval' {} \+)
```

- Using `while` over the `for` is better, because the filenames could contain spaces. /probably not in this case, but anyway :)/
- using `grep -c '' "$file"` is sometimes better (when the last line in the file, doesn't contains the `\n` character (the `wc` counts the `\n` characters in the file)
- the `find` with the `\+` instead of the `\;` is more efficient

Answer (score 2):

Problem seems to be here:

```
if [ wc -l < $file -gt 3 ]; then
```

Since you need to use command substitution here to make sure `wc -l` command executes first and then compare the result:

```
if [[ $(wc -l < "$file") -gt 3 ]]; then
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to execute your `wc`, more like:

```
   if [[ $(wc -l < $file) -gt 3 ]]; then
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(grep -H "base64_decode\|eval" ./*.php | cut -d: -f1);
do
        echo $file;
        head -n 3 $file;
        if [[ $(wc -l < $file) -gt 3 ]];
                then
                        tail -n 3 $file
                fi;
done
```

I tested and seems to work fine.

But, be carefull ... if php has 4 lines, you will see:

```
line1

line2

line3

line2

line3

line4
```

EDIT: changed the script above to grep inside files.

```
cat a.php
asdasd
asd
base64_decode
l
a
```

and result

```
./test2.sh
./a.php
asdasd
asd
base64_decode
base64_decode
l
a
```

Comment: No, this is an untested code :) and didn't works. The `find . -name "*.php" | grep "base64_decode\|eval"` will search for **filenames** containing the `base64_decode\|eval` and not the files those content contains `base64_decode\|eval`... You need to use as the OP - the `-il` for the grep.

Comment: my mistake ... i thought the name should contain "base64_decode\|eval". Please don't say this is untested code just to show off ... this is tested code, i just thought the name should contain those 2 values.

Comment: OK, it is a tested code - but not an answer to the OP needs... ;)